# Integrate tabs in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an Activity that extends Fragment. I want a add a tab inside the Fragment.

In this Activity I want to add two tabs

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Fragment_Coupons extends Fragment {
    TabHost tabHost;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    public Fragment_Coupons() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupon, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all

> Anything That extends a Fragment will be a Fragment, You cant have an Activity that Extends Fragment

If you want to know about tabs you can read about [Adding Navigation Tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

1. Basically you need to set Navigation type for Action Bar

   ```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
   ```
2. Add the 2 tabs You want to the Action Bar

   ```
      Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                          .setText(R.string.artist)
                          .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                                  this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
       actionBar.addTab(tab);

       tab = actionBar.newTab()
                      .setText(R.string.album)
                      .setTabListener(new TabListener<AlbumFragment>(
                              this, "album", AlbumFragment.class));
       actionBar.addTab(tab);
   ```
3. Implement the ActionBar.TabListener interface.